# Is it possible to install CNTK on a macbook?

Tags: macos, installation, cntk

It is possible to install Microsoft CNTK on a macbook? I have OS X El Capitan. The official Microsoft documentation at https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Setup-CNTK-on-your-machine doesn't provide any information for mac users.

Thank you

Answer (score 12):

As of June 2017, you can only run CNTK on OSX using Docker (which will run a Linux container)

Documentation from Microsoft is available here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/CNTK-Docker-Containers

If you want to run the CPU version of CNTK (as opposed to a GPU enabled) you'll need to pull a particular version of the docker container. See: https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/cntk/

I recommend using the following for CPU CNTK:

`docker pull microsoft/cntk:2.0-cpu-python3.5`

Once you've pulled the container above, you can use Jupyter Notebooks to look at tutorials etc:

First, run the container:

```
docker run -d -p 8888:8888 --name cntk-jupyter-notebooks -t microsoft/cntk:2.0-cpu-python3.5
```

Then run this command:

```
docker exec -it cntk-jupyter-notebooks bash -c "source /cntk/activate-cntk && jupyter-notebook --no-browser --port=8888 --ip=0.0.0.0 --notebook-dir=/cntk/Tutorials --allow-root"
```

You'll want to access the shell to run CNTK commands. You can attach a bash shell using docker.

Get your container id

```
docker ps
```

Then attach a shell

```
docker exec -it <container_id> bash
```

Comment: Can the GPU version be used on a Mac, either through a local Windows VM/docker or would it require a eGPU?

Answer (score 3):

While it might not be supported on Mac directly, you can always use a virtual machine to get around.

1. You can setup docker in your local environment.

   https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/
2. Follow its documentations on how to install on Docker

   https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/CNTK-Docker-Containers

Comment: Docker is the way to go (at the moment). We've successfully used Docker for Mac users in CNTK tutorials, no issues reported.

Comment: The Docker image just got an update to the latest version, 2.0 beta 8, on [Dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/cntk/)

Answer (score 2):

We currently support both Linux and Windows. Mac support is on our ToDo or would be interested in community contribution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently building CNTK on a linux machine without root access, installing every dependency with linuxbrew (a fork of homebrew). So I think is possible to build on MacOS natively. You can try building it from source with [CNTK linux manual to build from source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/setup-cntk-on-linux). Let me know if you have any issue.